# How to identify contracts created using deployer contracts from the logs?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, events, logs, receipts

I am interested in keeping track of each new contract created on Ethereum. So far, I have been looking at the transaction logs, there is a field `to` if this field has no value, that means it is a contract creation transaction and the field `contractAddress` in the transaction receipt will have the address for that contract.

However, recently I noticed some contracts were deployed using a deployer contract (contract factory). My question is how to identify and keep track of such contracts by looking at the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult task to do when the factories do not emit any event about creating contracts (which we cannot assume they do). You cannot get it from the logs. Instead, you need to have an archive node with tracing enabled and use transaction tracing for that. These create calls are usually referred as "internal transactions". Assuming you only want to query ETH archive node and do not want to use any other online services. Below is one way to solve it.
Sample code :

```
contract Test2{}
contract Test{
    function test_deploy() public {
        Test2 test = new Test2();
    }
}
```

When you call `test_deploy`, the logs will show nothing. And you have to trace that tx to analyze and get the new contract address:
You can use `geth` [evm tracing](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/developers/evm-tracing) to analyze the trace. For example the call to `test_deploy` has hash `0x12345...` and your `geth` running at `localhost:8545`:

Step 1: Get the trace: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id": 1, "method": "debug_traceTransaction", "params": ["0x12345..."]}' localhost:8545`

Step 2: Analyze the trace:

```json
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    ...
    "structLogs": [
      ...

      {
        "pc": 75,
        "op": "CREATE",
        "gas": 69066,
        "gasCost": 32000,
        "depth": 1,
        "stack": ["0x21e6fd1c", "0x33", "0x0", "0xd5", "0x80", "0x0"]
      },
      ...
      {
        "pc": 29,
        "op": "RETURN",
        "gas": 36400,
        "gasCost": 0,
        "depth": 2,
        "stack": ["0xb6", "0x0"]
      },
      {
        "pc": 76,
        "op": "DUP1",
        "gas": 579,
        "gasCost": 3,
        "depth": 1,
        "stack": [
          "0x21e6fd1c",
          "0x33",
          "0x0",
          "0xc9902788795009bfb19dfaa1e0ca67e48eb40ff3"
        ]
      },
      ....
      {
        "pc": 52,
        "op": "STOP",
        "gas": 535,
        "gasCost": 0,
        "depth": 1,
        "stack": ["0x21e6fd1c"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here the interesting opcode are `CREATE` or `CREATE2` and the `RETURN` of create. The top of the stack right after the return of CREATE will have the address of the created contract: `0xc9902788795009bfb19dfaa1e0ca67e48eb40ff3`. This simple sequence is not a 100% correct solution because there may have **nested creates** (the constructor of Test2 creates another contract) or the constructor of Test2 calling some external contracts, you need to take care of these cases also.

Alternative choices: other service providers (e.g. Quicknode, alchemy) have paid API for tracing with better parsed results, also etherscan's tx tracing and showing internal transactions are also worth considering for a simpler but more expensive way to solve it.